# Android OutOfMemory error ImageView

Tags: android, memory

```
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 14400012 byte allocation with 5645520 free bytes and 5MB until OOM
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:726)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:547)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1014)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:3730)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3603)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1852)
            at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:408)
            at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:17228)
            at alexcz.shapetest.Test.nextQ(Test.java:89)
            at alexcz.shapetest.Test$1.onClick(Test.java:54)
```

---

**Error ^^**

The error occurs when any of the onClick events are triggered. All the other images show up except these 2. Both these images are not big and around 600x600. In the code the error occurs at

```
nextq.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nextq);
result.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.correct);
```

Thanks in advance.

GITHUB:https://github.com/alex578344/ShapeTestLogic

Comment: "around 600x600" -- are you sure about that? The allocation size that is failing would fit something more like 600x6000.

Comment: Yeah both are around 600x600 @CommonsWare

Comment: Have you considered using an image management library like Picasso?

Comment: @WoogieNoogie I added to github if intrested to look at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:largeHeap ="true"
```

Not a panacea, and the most recent method of optimization. Explore [this official guide](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) to learn more.

I recommend replace ImageView to [subsampling-scale-image-view](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view). It is very convenient and fast library with a compatible ImageViewinterface. It will ship the picture in parts, which excludes this exception.

Answer (score -1):

Put  largeHeap in your AndroidManifest.xml

`<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Test"
        android:largeHeap="true">`

Comment: This response is typical rookie mistake - to defer the problem.

Comment: Prefer not to use it unless you know what you app is doing and what is leaking to the memory.